# ValueChangeEvent for primefaces spinner is null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces and spinner component. I want to detect in changEvent method which button of spinner is clicked. I hoped I would get oldValue and newValue but the ValueChangeEvent is null. I am new in Java EE. could some body help me. my English is also not so good.

this is a part of my index.xhtml:

```
<h:form> 
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" styleClass="ui-grid">
        <h:outputLabel for="ajaxSpinner" value="Ajax Spinner: " />
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:spinner id="ajaxSpinner" value="#{spinnerView.number5}"  >
                <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="ajaxSpinnerValue" process="@this" listener="#{spinnerView.changeEvent(event)}" />
            </p:spinner>
            <h:outputText id="ajaxSpinnerValue" value="#{spinnerView.number5}" style="padding-left: 10px" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

and this is Bean-Class

```
package test.ctrl;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("spinnerView")
@SessionScoped
public class WebBean implements Serializable{
    private int number1;
    private int number2;
    private int number3;
    private int number4;
    private int number5;

    public int getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }

    public void setNumber1(int number1) {
        this.number1 = number1;
    }

    public int getNumber2() {
        return number2;
    }

    public void setNumber2(int number2) {
        this.number2 = number2;
    }

    public int getNumber3() {
        return number3;
    }

    public void setNumber3(int number3) {
        this.number3 = number3;
    }

    public int getNumber4() {
        return number4;
    }

    public void setNumber4(int number4) {
        this.number4 = number4;
    }

    public int getNumber5() {
        return number5;
    }

    public void setNumber5(int number5) {
    
        this.number5 = number5;
    }

    public void callBean(){
        System.out.println("Ausgabe" + number5); 
    
    }

    public void changeEvent(ValueChangeEvent ev){
        System.out.println("Ausgabe:"+ev.getOldValue() +"--" +ev.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing your listener to `listener="#{spinnerView.changeEvent}"`  Remove the parameter it is passed automatically when you declare the ajax listener.

Comment: IS valueChange a real event? And I doubt on it you have the old and new event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change p:spiner and p:ajax tags as follow:

```
<p:spinner id="ajaxSpinner" value="#{spinnerView.number5}" valueChangeListener="#{spinnerView.changeEvent}" >
    <p:ajax  update="@form" process="@this, ajaxSpinner" />
</p:spinner>
```